# jquery ui map v3: programmatically open infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Ok, i have a dynamic generated google map (using the jquery ui map v3 plugin).
What map data to appear, depends on user input/selection.

I open the map like this:

```
    map_lat = parseFloat(xxxxxxxxxx);
    map_long = parseFloat(xxxxxxxxxxxx);
    map_zoom = parseInt(xxxxxxxxxxxx);

    myCenter = map_lat+","+map_long;
    myCenter = myCenter.toString(); 

    $("#my_map").width(600).height(620);

    $("#my_map").gmap({
        "center": myCenter, 
        "zoom": map_zoom,
        "disableDefaultUI": false
    });
    populateMap( *varius options here* );
```

The function to populate my map with markers and data is:

```
function populateMap( *varius options here* );
{
    var htmlData = "", // will hold a list of links for user to interact. Each link must open appropriate marker info window
        htmlDataShow = '' // will hold some html data along with the link list
    ;   


    $("#my_map").gmap("clear", "markers");
    $("#point-view").hide();

    $.getJSON( "path_to_json_file", function(data) 
    { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) 
        {
            htmlData += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick=\'openGMarker("'+marker.id+'")\'>'+marker.title+'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';

            $("#my_map").gmap("addMarker", 
            { 
                "position": new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                "bounds": true ,
                "icon": marker.icon,
                "id":marker.id,
            }).click(function() 
            {
                $("#my_map").gmap("openInfoWindow", { "content": marker.content }, this);
            });
        });



        htmlDataShow = '<h2 class="fut20 white lightStripTitleFull">Select a point to view on map</h2><div class="graystrip"><p>'+htmlData+'</p></div>';
        $("#point-view").empty().html(htmlDataShow).show();


    });
}
```

The above function will generate on page the list of avaialble markers/links for user to interact (click to show details on infowindow).

For user to be able to interact with the links i have this function:

```
function openGMarker(id)
{
    $('#my_map').gmap('closeInfoWindow');
    var marker = $('#my_map').gmap('get', 'markers')[id];
    //console.log(marker);
}
```

This function will get the id of the link/marker and open the proper infowindow.
I managed to get the id part, but so far i cannot understnad how to open the infowindow.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By providing a working example, I think you can solve your problem.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/VwMyv/2/), you can understand it better.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Food Waste and Organics workshop'
});
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

To open the `infoWindow` pro grammatically, add a **click listener**,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

This a basic sample, if possible make your own fiddle and provide the link.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: yes i have found this example in another post but i can't get it to work on my code.

Comment: @andrew Make a jsfiddle and provide the link. so that I can check your code.  meanwhile let me try to create a fiddle for you.